# Store container in path

Tags: docker

I am trying to use Docker to compile some stuff. The problem is that the default disc partition is pretty full and I want to store the container in an alternative path, not in the default path. Is there any option to add when running the container, such as `docker run -it ... -o /media/user/my_storage_unit`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible. You could try cleaning up the space used by docker with `docker prune`

Comment: you can move all the docker related data to a new partition though